# How do I toggle the display of a scrollbar?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, webkit, scrollbar

I would like to toggle the display of a scrollbar on a DIV container based on whether the mouse is over the container or not. So, only show the scrollbar when the mouse is over the DIV container (and the DIV is overflowing with content, of course).

I have tried to change the overflow from hidden to auto and vice-versa with CSS like the following:

```
div.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.container:hover {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This does toggle the display of the scrollbar, but when the scroll bar is shown again, it is reset to the top. I need to keep the position of the scrollbar at its last state.

What is the easiest way to toggle the display of a scrollbar? I am trying to stay with a pure CSS solution, but *minimal* JavaScript would probably be OK.

Comment: It's not reset to the top for me in Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/nvN8n It does get nudged a little if it was all the way at the bottom but that's a spacing problem that's easily fixed with an increased width on hover.

Comment: Not reset for me in Chrome (14.0.835).

Comment: I highly doubt there's a cross-browser pure CSS solution here. I hope you like JavaScript.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using Chrome (13.0.782.215) on Win 7. When I hover over the container, then off, then back on, the scrollbar is reset to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is arguably a WebKit bug. [Consider reporting it.](https://bugs.webkit.org/)

**Edit:** There's already [at least one existing bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47963). Though that one is somewhat unloved.

---

For now, here's a silly workaround:

```
$('.container').hover(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $(this).scrollTop(0).scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/C5vmK/

This can easily be written without jQuery if you're not already using it.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Yup, it already worked in Chrome for me also. I've been testing in Safari for that very reason, where it's still broken :)

Comment: FYI in the latest stable Chrome it's broken 2